# Add new tab dynamically in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, ios9, tabbar

In Tab bar Controller, Initially I had added 3 tab bar items in it.After successful login, I need to add one more item dynamically in my current Tab bar Controller . Is it possible to add dynamically ? Below is the code i have tried but its not working.

```
 if (AppContext.loginUser.userId!=nil) {
        UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4;// = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
        tabBarItem4.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectedProfileTab"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
        tabBarItem4.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Profiletab"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
        tabBarItem4.title = @"Profile";
        tabBarItem4.tag =4;

        ProfileVC *profile = loadViewController(TabbarSB, VC_Profile);

        UINavigationController *nv=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:profile];

        NSMutableArray *arrayOfTabBars=[AppContext.mainTabbar.viewControllers mutableCopy];
        [arrayOfTabBars addObject:nv];


       // [AppContext.mainTabbar setViewControllers:nil];

        [AppContext.mainTabbar setViewControllers:arrayOfTabBars];


        //AppContext.mainTabbar.viewControllers = arrayOfTabBars;
      // [self.tabBarController.tabBarController addChildViewController:profile];

    }
```

Comment: ofcourse you can. You need to do it in your tabcontroller class!!!!

Comment: Yes, You need to change the `rootViewController` and assign new `TabBar` controller.

Comment: @Mr.T Thanks for your answer. Would you please elaborate "tabcontroller class" or can you give me a reference link ?

Comment: you have .h and .m files for every controller. Like the same, you need to create a .h and .m file for UITabBarController and you need to modify the setViewControllers array

Comment: The right way to do this is: Create ProfileVC - Attach to UINavigationController - Add navigation controller to viewControllers array - Create tab bar item with `profile.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];`

Comment: You don't need to subclass `UITabBarController` for this. You can access tabbar controller by using `self.tabBarController`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that programmatically:

```
if (AppContext.loginUser.userId!=nil) {
    // First, create your view controller
    ProfileVC *profile = loadViewController(TabbarSB, VC_Profile);

    // then embed it to a navigation controller
    // this is not required, only if you need it
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:profile];

    // Get viewControllers array and add navigation controller
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
    [viewControllers addObject:nav];

    // Set back the array
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

    // Create tab bar item for ProfileVC
    profile.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:image selectedImage:selectedImage];
}
```